# Can the Killing Curse be used to block another Killing Curse?

Tags: harry-potter, avada-kedavra

If one character used the Avada Kedavra against an armed wizard (has his wand on the ready), can that armed wizard use the same curse to block Avada Kedavra? I know Avada Kedavra is considered "unblockable", but assuming that it is the same spell, I wonder if both curses would just nullify each other, if they are cast will the same amount of intent and power.

Comment: I seriously doubt it - it would take significant effort to intentionally strike the incoming curse with your own, and if you are intending to strike the incoming curse (NOT your foe) you likely can't cast the Killing Curse - it has to be cast with intent to kill, not with intent to block an attack.

Comment: I can already see this in the HNQ list.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

Unforgivable Curses have to be cast with a desire to make pain, control, kill, as we see in OOTP:

> “Never used an Unforgivable Curse before, have you, boy?” she yelled. She had abandoned her baby voice now. “You need to mean them, Potter! You need to really want to cause pain — to enjoy it — righteous anger won’t hurt me for long — I’ll show you how it is done, shall I? I’ll give you a lesson —”
>
> <sub>-*Harry Potter and the Order of Phoenix,* chapter 36</sub>

If you're casting it with the intention of blocking, it probably won't work.

This is in addition to the fact that it would be nearly impossible to hit the spell on purpose...

Answer (score 2):

### The spells would most likely ricochet following precedent.

**Spells hitting head on tend to ricochet**

> Jets of light shot from both wands, hit each other in midair, and
>   ricocheted off at angles — Harry’s hit Goyle in the face, and Malfoy’s hit Hermione.

**but what about a spell ricocheting Avada Kedavra you ask?**

> yelled his best hope to the heavens,
>   pointing Draco’s wand:
>
> **‘Avada Kedavra!’**
>
> **‘Expelliarmus!’**
>
> The bang was like a cannon-blast and the golden flames that erupted
>   between them, at the dead centre of the circle they had been treading,
>   marked the point where the **spells collided**. **Harry saw Voldemort’s**
>   g**reen jet meet his own spell**, saw the Elder Wand fly high, dark
>   against the sunrise, spinning across the enchanted ceiling like the
>   head of Nagini, spinning through the air towards the master it would
>   not kill, who had come to take full possession of it at last. And
>   Harry, with the unerring skill of the Seeker, caught the wand in his
>   free hand as Voldemort fell back- wards, arms splayed, the slit pupils
>   of the scarlet eyes rolling upwards. Tom Riddle hit the floor with a
>   mundane finality, his body feeble and shrunken, the white hands empty,
>   the snake-like face vacant and unknowing. **Voldemort was dead, killed**
>   **by his own rebounding curse**, and Harry stood with two wands in his
>   hand, staring down at his enemy’s shell.

**and again**

> “I miscalculated, my friends, I admit it. My curse was deflected
>   by the woman’s foolish sacrifice, and it **rebounded** upon myself.
>   Aaah . . . pain beyond pain, my friends; nothing could have pre-
>   pared me for it.

**Avada Kedavra has precedent of being able to be richocheted.**

Comment: That was special circumstance. Voldemort's spell didn't work in that scenario purely because the Elder Wand's allegiance was with Harry and so would not kill him. It's not exactly something any wizard could accomplish.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that Avada Kedavra + Expelliarmus adds up to the same as 2 AKs.

Comment: @TheDarkLord expelliarmus is a relatively simple spell, if it can cause an AK to ricochet, why cant another AK? not to mention we have general precedent that any spell hitting another mid air causes it to ricochet

Answer (score -2):

### **Only if both wands share the same core**

> When a duel occurred between wizards with wand cores harvested from the same creature, simultaneous spell-casting by both parties would trigger a rare, powerful effect called Priori Incantatem.

If both wands share the same core, then two wizards casting **Avada Kedavra** at the same time would induce *Priori Incantatem* and lock the two wizards together until the spell ran its course.

Of course, if the two wands didn't have the same core and the two wizards (assuming both had intent to kill) cast **Avada Kedavra** at the same time, it would simply result in the deaths of both wizards.

Comment: priori incantatem is between 2 wands sharing the same core, but not needing to have the same spell cast.

Comment: OP was referring specifically to the same spell being cast at each other, which is why I said "the same spell at the same time". I've edited my answer.

Answer (score -2):

### No

The only known protections against avada kadavra are

- Avoiding being hit by dodging or using a physical object
- sacrificial love, it is not known if this protects you from the spell, or just the person who killed the sacrificing party.
- Sharing a core and forcing them to battle, can result in priori imcantartum.
- your opponent using a wand that owes its allegence to you allowing it to rebound.

Comment: Love magic protects you from an individual, not a specific spell, as evidenced by the fact that Voldemort could not touch Harry in _Philosopher's Stone_. That's why he needed some of Harry's blood when he was resurrected in _Goblet of Fire_. In addition, because she shares the same blood, Aunt Petunia was also protected from Voldemort.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo yes. So it offers protection by proxy

Comment: I'm just saying it _is_ known what love magic protects you from, and it is "the person who killed the sacrificing party", not "the spell".